# How to show the google admob in custom keyboard for iOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have created the Custom Keyboard App for iOS. and I added the google admob banner view on keyboard.view, but it cannot show the google admob banner, and is empty.

Ad Unit ID and admob module are working exactly on other mobile apps.

Why admob cannot be displaying on custom keybaord app?

Comment: i want same thing.. did you get any solution.?

Comment: hi did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we cannot use admob under the UIInputViewController with the error message "App is in background and background loading is disabled. Ignoring request.".
Please ask Google advisor about the fix schedule for this issue.